# PowerShell Menu Script

Tags: powershell

How can I do PowerShell menu script showing items on both sides, sample here

```
======================================
1) Start Service     2) Stop Service
3) Service Status    4) Exit

=======================================
```

Comment: purely as an aside, have you looked at the `Out-GridView` cmdlet? it can be used as a quick menu ... and can accept either single or multiple selections.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a here-string to show it, I assume you already know how to take input and do these actions:

```
write-host @'
======================================
1) Start Service     2) Stop Service
3) Service Status    4) Exit

=======================================
'@
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to elaborate on the helpful answer by @Wasif Hasan's answer.

There are number of ways you can do it. In the example below I combine a here string (aka [splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-7.1)) with a `switch` [(see about switch)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_switch?view=powershell-7.1) to select the menu item

```
$menu = read-host @'
======================================
1) Start Service     2) Stop Service
3) Service Status    4) Exit
=======================================
'@

switch ($menu) {
    1 { "Start service" }
    2 {"Stop service"}
    3 {"Service status"}
    4 {"Exit"}
    Default {"Service status"}
}
```